# DataGridViewButtonColumn enabling buttons binding boolean field

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a custom object (say `MyObject`) with a bool property called `IsEnabled`. I bound a collection of `MyObject` to a `DataGridView` setting the `DataPropertyName` for each column.

I'd like to enable the buttons in a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` by the value of the `IsEnabled` property. How can I obtain this without implementing a custom column? Is it possible?

Binding the field to the column it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that buttons in a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` cannot be disabled, so, following this article, the only way to obtain what I want is to implement a custom DataGrid column type:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx

Not very practical...