# How can I change a "True" in a DataGridView to Yes?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

Basically it says it all in my question. I don't know how to that. I've tried this ([replace true/false in datagridview columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914411/replace-true-false-in-datagridview-columns)) but it doesn't work for me. 
My SQL code is:

```
create table ejemploc
(
id int not null,
nombre varchar(35),
opcion1 varchar(5),
opcion2 varchar(5),
opcion3 varchar(5),
constraint pkid primary key (id)
)engine=innodb;
```

and my code to populate my DataGridView is:

```
private void CargaDataGridView()
        {
            conexion.Open();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from ejemploc";
                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rd.GetValue(0), rd.GetValue(1), rd.GetValue(2), rd.GetValue(3), rd.GetValue(4));
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I got the answer, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/491243/jw and https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711633/vond-ritz

change `"cmd.CommandText = "select * from ejemploc";"` to

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  id,nombre, CASE WHEN opcion1 = 'True' THEN 'Sí' ELSE 'No' END opcion1, CASE WHEN opcion2 = 'True' THEN 'Sí' ELSE 'No' END opcion2, CASE WHEN opcion3 = 'True' THEN 'Sí' ELSE 'No' END opcion3 FROM ejemploc";
```

Comment: what index of rd is the value u want to convert?

Comment: I try to convert rd.GetValue(2), rd.GetValue(3), rd.GetValue(4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  id,
        nombre,
        CASE WHEN opcion1 = 'True' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END opcion1,
        CASE WHEN opcion2 = 'True' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END opcion2,
        CASE WHEN opcion3 = 'True' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END opcion3
FROM    ejemploc
```

or if `true = 1` then,

```
SELECT  id,
        nombre,
        CASE WHEN opcion1 = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END opcion1,
        CASE WHEN opcion2 = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END opcion2,
        CASE WHEN opcion3 = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END opcion3
FROM    ejemploc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand wher to put it. In a new event? if so, which?

Comment: replace ur query with this.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I can't thank both of you in the same comment, so I did in separate ones.