# Howto format values in DataGridView which is having Entity Framework classes as DataSource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, datagridview, formatting

I have some simple EF Code-First class and context:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Value { get; set; }          
}

public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And I have DataGridView which is binded to that context:

```
private void Form1_Load void (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductContext _context = new ProductContext();

    // Load data from the database into entities. 
    _context.Categories.Load();

    // Enabling two-way binding between DataGridView and entities
    DataGridView.DataSource = _context.Products.Local.ToBindingList();
}
```

And I need to implement **Product.Value** formatting (depending on **Product.ValueType**) before displaying it to DataGridView (for example, convert **byte[]** representation of **Double** to real **Double**).
But I have no idea how to do that..

P.S. All I've found googling is that I can use **Format** and **Parse** events of **Binding** class (which is after that added to DataBindings property of the control).
But as far as I know, **Binding** class is suitable for simple controls like **TextBox**, **Button**, etc.

So I need your help..

Thank you.

Comment: I've answered similar question check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980981/show-yes-no-instead-true-false-in-datagridview/17981584#17981584

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth I've expected to get solution somewhere on th EF or binding side. But your approach suggests manipulating data after binding complete and before actually displaying value to cell.. And it works for me - many thx :)