# Replace value of datagridview column while setting data Source

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am custom binding my data grid view,
Now if my data columns has true value then I want to show Yes in the column else if its null or false I want to show No to the User, 
how can I achieve this.

I have tried with

```
dgvAppointments.Columns["colBillReady"].DataPropertyName = dtAppointments.Columns["BillReady1"].ToString() == "True" ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: [Does this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17981584/2530848)?

Comment: yes it did helped ... but quite lengthy process.. handling at db only seems good option here

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I mark it as duplicate as it helped you.