# C# custom datagridview columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I customize my DataGridView's columns (insert image, set text with differenet font...) based on the current values of the columns ?

For example:

if the column's value = 0, I want to display the word "**NO**" and if the column's value = 1, I want to display the word "**YES**" (or put a different image)

In JAVA I use `CellRenderer`, and if I change the column's value from "0" to "1" the renderer itself take the charge to change the word automaticly from "**NO**" to "**YES**".

How can I do the same in C# ?

Comment: Use Rowdatabound event of grid...

Comment: More details pls or a good link, I'm new with C#, and thnx :).

Comment: http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource17-RowDatabound-event-tips-and-tricks-in-Gridview-control.aspx.aspx

Comment: @Dhaval `DataGridView` is not equal to `GridView`. I believe OP is using winforms.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel hmmmm what do you mean "winforms" ??

Comment: For image you need to use [ImageColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and for changing text you can use [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980981/show-yes-no-instead-true-false-in-datagridview)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thnx it's what I'm looking for :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CellFormatting` event ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Example:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText == "Value")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            int intValue = (int)e.Value;
            e.Value = (intValue == 0) ? "NO" : "YES";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the right answer just one more thing I'm creating datagridview dynamicly, how can I associate this method to a datagridview that created dynamicly ?

Comment: or should I create a class that extends from DataGridView ?

Comment: You should assing event handler to `CellFormatting` event: `yourDataGridView.CellFormatting += dataGridView1_CellFormatting;`

Comment: thnx but why "+=" instead of "=" ?

Comment: Because it's the way how you can subscribe to an event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx).

Comment: thnx a lot my friend :).