# How to replace value (boolean) of cell in datagridview to a string C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm try replace value of column "Trạng thái" but type of column not support to put a string into

My code:

```
        public void loadDataGridView()
        {
            dataGridViewDKOnline.DataSource = dangKyOnline_Bll.dsDangKyOnline();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewDKOnline.Rows)
            {
                if((bool)row.Cells["TrangThai"].Value == true)
                {
                    row.Cells["TrangThai"].Value = "Đã xử lý";
                }    
                else
                    row.Cells["TrangThai"].Value = "Chưa xử lý";
            }
        }
```

And error:

[image]

Is there any way I can do that ? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;

public void loadDataGridView()
{
    dataGridViewDKOnline.DataSource = dangKyOnline_Bll.dsDangKyOnline();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewDKOnline.Rows)
    {
        var cell = row.Cells["TrangThai"];
        if(cell != null && Boolean.Parse(cell.Value))
        {
            cell.Value = "Đã xử lý";
        }    
        else
        {
            cell.Value = "Chưa xử lý";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it and gave it an error: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Comment: Does the string have the value "True" or "False" (casing is irrelevant)?

Comment: I misunderstood you and tried again but still get the same error

Comment: I edited the code to be more clear...if you try that, what is the error that you get?

Comment: Also what is the value of row.Cells["TrangThai"].Value

Comment: TrangThai is bit in MSSQL

Comment: you'd have to convert it to a string first

Comment: You can not set the value of `TrangThai` to the string `"Đã xử lý"` if it is BIT. Probably you want to have the boolean values formatted in a different way. See this to see how to do it: [show Yes/NO instead True/False in datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17980981/880990). Just replace yes/no by Đã xử lý/Chưa xử lý.

Comment: I have fixed the problem using the way of the post you just tagged. Thank you very much