# Display string value instead of boolean checkbox using datasource?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, boolean

Boolean is for storing economically in SQL Database. But the datagridview when using datasource function in C# just show true or false by the checkbox each row.

I want to display the string value in the datagridview, not Boolean using checkbox .

True  = "Spin On"
False = "Element"
How can I change the checkbox to a string value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options to obtain this:

### Binding

First, you could change the binding during on `RowDataBound`  of `GridView`. Give a look at [this example](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/01/19/how-to-display-yes-or-no-instead-of-checkbox-while-binding-boolean-value-with-gridview/), where you have the following class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Roll { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

and you can change the default behavior of `GridView` as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the RowDataBound event of the GridView2 control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Student s = (Student)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (s.Status == true)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

### Formatting

Another way to address this problem consists in using `custom formatting`, handling the `CellFormatting` *event* according to your needs:

```
void gridView2_CellFormatting(object s, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs evt)
{
     if (evt.ColumnIndex == yourcolumnIndex){
         if (evt.Value is bool){
             evt.Value = ((bool)evt.Value) ? "Yes" : "No";
             evt.FormattingApplied = true;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm coding the window form, So I'm choosing the Formatting solution, but I have a problem here. The value is change to string value, but the cell ( or the column ) type is not change. I think it's still checkboxcolumn.

Comment: Yes, because in your case you have to replace also the bound column with a new column of different type. See the update to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9914662/2200058)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Converter`  will allow you to do it easily

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(Boolean), typeof(String))]
    internal class BooleanToStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Boolean state = (Boolean)value;
            return state ? "Spin On" : "Element";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

then, in your XAML, bind your `String` (a label in my example) to the `Boolean` ('state' variable in the example) using the Converter :

```
 <Label Content="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter }, Mode=OneWay}" />
```